# Dell Poweredge 1850 problem installing OS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, raid

I have a Dell PowerEdge 1850 with 2x 73GB SCSI hard disks in the front. I am trying to install Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition, but when I try I either get a blue screen, it won't boot to disk at all or won't find hard disks.

Has anyone got a similar server so I could possibly replicate their RAID settings or walk me through them?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you need:

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R146318&SystemID=PWE_1850&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=10655&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=8&catid=36&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=36&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=204270

Download this iso image and create a bootable CD with it then boot the server to this CD. This should allow you to install Windows Server 2003 with the correct drivers for whichever SCSI or RAID controller is installed in the server.

Comment: +1 This Dell disk will make this much easier!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Dell servers but a quick Google search showed up the following answer:

> easy method is to use the server build cd and do during setup or;
>   ctrl-m during post > configure > easy configuration, press spacebar twice to select both 
>   disks, enter and press spacebar again. This enters span-1 in the box. Press f10 to 
>   configure, select raid1 and scroll to accept. Press esc and save config. Then initialise the > volume, exit and reboot.

*Taken from http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/p/19269162/19466979.aspx*

Comment: did the above, i just get "strike F1 to reboot, F2 for setup utility" Bios is AO2, how can i upgrade to Ao6 without a floppy?

Comment: Try downloading the update and burning to a CD.